# making External Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code. It's working but I need to make the script file external. I want to create another file which is sample.js and inside it is the script file for the placeholder. I tried making it external but I don't know how would I call the function that I used in the script.

This is the html file with the internal script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            </head>
        <body>
         <input type="text" placeholder="sample" id="sample2">

    <script type="text/javascript">
function hasPlaceholderSupport() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  return ('placeholder' in input);
}

if(!hasPlaceholderSupport()){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0,  count = inputs.length;i<count;i++){
        if(inputs[i].getAttribute('placeholder')){
            inputs[i].style.cssText = "color:#939393;font-style:italic;"
            inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
            inputs[i].onclick = function(){
                if(this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder")){
                    this.value = '';
                    this.style.cssText = "color:#000;font-style:normal;"
                }
            }
            inputs[i].onblur = function(){
                if(this.value == ''){
                    this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
                    this.style.cssText = "color:#939393;font-style:italic;"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure it's not just a matter of `<script src="sample.js"></script>`?

Comment: _" it doesn't work"_ In what way does it not work?  Do you see any errors in the console etc?

Comment: Can you show the *exact* contents of the external script, as well as the `<script>` tag you used to include it?

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. 
Sorry for the wrong composition of paragraph. How can I make it work if I put the script into a external javascript file? How do I call the function hasPlaceholderSupport?

Comment: @Styxes Show us how you're including it as an external script.  My guess is you've put it as a resource in the `<head>` so it runs before the DOM is ready, as opposed to where it is now.  But that's _just a guess_ - without seeing what you've _actually_ tried, _we don't know_.

Comment: HMTL File

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
 <script src="sample.js">
 hasPlaceholderSupport();</script>
        </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" placeholder="sample" id="sample2">
        
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: Thank you. My bad I put it in the <head>
Thank you! and Im very sorry for my poor paragraph composition

Comment: @Styxes Put the script before your closing body tag..

Comment: @Styxes, also, `<script src="sample.js"> hasPlaceholderSupport();</script>` is incorrect. You can have either the `src` attribute _or_ the content in between the tags: `<script src="sample.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment...

> HMTL File `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script src="sample.js"> hasPlaceholderSupport();</script> </head> <body> <input type="text" placeholder="sample" id="sample2"> </body> </html>`

You cannot have both an external script reference **and** internal script in the same tag.

Change...

```
<script src="sample.js"> hasPlaceholderSupport();</script>
```

To...

```
<script src="sample.js"></script>
<script>hasPlaceholderSupport();</script>
```

**But the important part is** that you must put it at the end of the page, just before the `</body>` tag.  Otherwise your calls to `getElementById` won't find anything.

Otherwise you need to implement "document ready" code (if you're using jQuery, something like `$(function() { ... });`